# What is the equation of warped disk in Cartesian or Spherical coordinate system?

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates

My teacher gave us the assignment to find the moment of inertia of any shape you want. So I decided to find the moment of inertia of our milky way galaxy.

I found out that our galaxy is shaped like a warped disk, not a flat. After I knew about that, I looked for the equation of the Milky Way's shape. But, to me, Nasa's and some high university papers had so many big wards that I could bearly understand what they were talking about(I'm Korean.. ^^). I'm sure that I can understand the equation if I had it, but I just can't find any information about them.

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what you know about these equations (shape).

Thank you!